# How to set permission on QSetting ini file

Tags: qt

I've created .ini file via QSetting object and want to set permission on this (created) file. Is that possible? 
PS
I'm working on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are property of a file on the filesystem, sometimes properties of certain file which OS stores somewhere else to make an emulation for permissions on filesystems which dont support them natively. Even talking about Win32 platform it could use different filesystems, like Fat/Fat32/NTFS/..anything else through 3rd party drivers, so it's for sure not something you could expect from cross-platform toolkit, and probably best way to write something yourself around WIN32 API.